# Can't stop drawing rectangles in qgraphicsview

Tags: python, pyqt5, rectangles

In my program I can select a button that sets self.rectmode=1. Once that variable is set to 1 it draws rectangles using mouse events on the qgraphicsview. After pressing a button to set self.rectmode=0 the program continues to draw rectangles using the mouse events. Am I missing some line to end the rectangle drawing event. My code is below thanks in advance:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):

    if (self.rectmode==1 and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and not  self._photo.pixmap().isNull()):
        self.origin = event.pos()
        self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
        self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
        self.rubberBand.show()
        self.changeRubberBand = True

     else:
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

    if self.rectmode==1 and self.changeRubberBand:
        self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
        self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())

    else:
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

    if self.rectmode==1 and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.changeRubberBand = False
        self.endpoint = event.pos()
        print(self.origin.x())
        print(self.origin.y())
        print(self.endpoint.x())
        print(self.endpoint.y())

    else:
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

Comment: From what can be seen in your excerpt everything should work as expected. Maybe there's some variable setting you didn't take into account. Can you expand your code to make it more comprehensive and *reproducible* (while keeping minimal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `rectmode` is always 1, I think that is what's causing the problem, here is a working example, I also removed the variable `changeRubberBand` because the same can be achieved with only the variable `rectMode`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QRect, QSize, Qt, QRubberBand, QVBoxLayout, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow


class PhotoViewer(QMainWindow):
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.origin = None
        self.endpoint = None
        self.rectMode = 0

        self.setFixedSize(1024, 768)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.rubberBand.hide()
        self.layout.addChildWidget(self.rubberBand)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.rectMode == 0 and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.rectMode = 1
        else:
            super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.rectMode == 1:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())

        else:
            super(PhotoViewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.rectMode == 1 and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.rectMode = 0
            self.endpoint = event.pos()
            print(self.origin.x())
            print(self.origin.y())
            print(self.endpoint.x())
            print(self.endpoint.y())

        else:
            super(PhotoViewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = PhotoViewer()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You were right there was something wrong with one of my buttons that turned off rectmode. I fixed that and now its properly turning off.